# Fourier coefficient of the dilation $f_m := f(mt)$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Let $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$. Furthermore, define the dilation $f_m$ by $f_m(t) := f(mt)$ for any $t \in \mathbb{T}$. I would like to show that
$$
\widehat{f_m}(n) =
\begin{cases}
\hat{f}(n/m) \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{if} \ m \ \text{divides}\ n\\
0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Letting $u = mt$, we have
\begin{align*}
\widehat{f_m}(n) &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(mt)e^{-int}\ dt\\
&= \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{m}\int_{-m\pi}^{m\pi}f(u)e^{-i(n/m)u}\ du
\end{align*}
I am not sure what to do next. It looks similar to $\hat{f}(n/m)$, but not quite there yet. I was wondering if anyone can help me with this problem.

Comment: **Hint:** split up the interval $[-m\pi,\,m\pi]$ to $m$ equal parts.